# Font Awesome Icon Types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, font-awesome

I am working in React with typescript. I have a header component that would take in an Icon name and render that. I am wondering how to make the icon prop type match an existing FontAwesome Icon.

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { IconLookup } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
    export const PageHeader = ({
  icon,
  children,
}: {
  icon: IconLookup;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) => {
  return (
    <PageHeaderWrapper>
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={icon} />
      {children}
    </PageHeaderWrapper>
  );
};
```

Comment: Is the issue that you only want to allow the names of icons which you have loaded in your local library? https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react#using

Comment: I'm playing with this but I don't think it's possible to get Typescript to infer the names based on an `add` function because the icon object has a general type `IconDefinition` and does not have string literal types for the name and pack.  I think you'll have to manually define a type for your supported icons.