# Where do I get the typescript types of the variable from library

Tags: javascript, typescript, font-awesome, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I have been working on a react-typescript project in which I am using a lot of external libraries and I frequently find myself using **any** type for those libraries. Please look at the code below for the demonstration

This is for the **Fontawesome library**

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import {
  faSquare,
} from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';

interface IProps {
  title: string;
  icon: any;
  onClick?: () => void;
  sx?: { [index: string]: string };
}

const icons ={
 title :_,
icon : faSquare
}
```

For the above code, what would be the type of **icon**. The value of which is **faSquare**. When I hovered over it the type is **IconDefinition**. But, I am not sure where to import it or if that is the way to do it.

Comment: [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67065507/font-awesome-icon-types) might help, duplicated version of yours

Comment: The icon is a component, so you have to add just React.ReactNode or JSX.Element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@fortawesome` packages embed their own types, thus the type of `icons.icon` is inferred automatically.

In VSCode, you can right-click and "Go to type definition" to check type.
In your case, the type of `faSquare` is `IconDefinition`

```js
export interface IconDefinition extends IconLookup {
  icon: [
    number, // width
    number, // height
    string[], // ligatures
    string, // unicode
    IconPathData // svgPathData
  ];
}
```

You can just add it to your import from `@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons'`

```
import {faSquare, IconDefinition} from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';
```